# Vagrant plugin install failing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant

I'm trying to install the vagrant-hostmanager plugin, but the install keeps failing. Here's the error:

```
Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/state_file.rb:47:in `save!': undefined method `sort!' for {}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Upgrading vagrant to 1.4 should fix this.

Comment: yup. that method was torn out last week. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/39b2539ec7821aa952ca36fbda4c68e35c8a2d41

Comment: Ah, I need 1.3.x to run genesis-wordpress though. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I had run in to the same issue trying to install the vagrant-berkshelf plugin - @misha's answer solved the problem for me also.

Comment: Worked for me as well.  Vagrant should still fix the uninstall script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran the vagrant uninstall script that comes with the vagrant 1.3.5 install and got the same error.  Then I nuked the hidden `$HOME/.vagrant.d` directory and that did the trick.

For me, there's a showstopper bug in 1.4.0 in configuring networking on RHEL (and variants), so I had to downgrade my development workstations to 1.3.5 (until Vagrant 1.4.1 is released with a fix): https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2614)

Comment: !! This removes all boxes and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can be more selective by figuring out what the issue is:

> ~/.vagrant.d 06:08:58 516$ grep -R state_file gems/
>   gems//gems/bindler-0.1.3/lib/bindler/bend_vagrant.rb:require
>   Vagrant.source_root.join('plugins/commands/plugin/state_file').to_s

So in my case "bindler".

> ~/.vagrant.d 06:11:43 519$
>   vagrant plugin uninstall bindler Uninstalling the 'bindler' plugin...
>   ~/.vagrant.d 06:12:39 520$ grep -R state_file gems/

All done!